.gz files are unsplittable. But if I place them in HDFS, they create multiple blocks depending on block size
We all know .gz is non-splittable, that means only single core can read it. This means, when I place a huge .gz file on HDFS, it should actually be present as a single block. I see it is getting split into blocks of 128MB, how is it possible to split in HDFS but not in Spark?

From HDFS perspective, Non splittable means that blocks cannot be processed in parallel  ; it does not mean a large file cannot span across more than one block.

So what you're trying to say is that, a 400MB gz file is actually split into 4 blocks and placed across HDFS. Then, why can't spark read it in parallel? At least 4 tasks should get spawned to pull the data. If all 4 blocks are necessary to be in place to read a gz file, then let it wait til 4 tasks fetch the data, combine those 4 blocks to get full gz file. Why does spark spawn only 1 task then?

Regarding your original question, Spark doesn't handle file storage. It reuses HDFS libraries for this. You can easily see number of blocks for any file. Non spittable files must be sequentially downloaded from the first block. It cannot reliably be fetched in parallel, then re-gathered and joined into a processable file... If you must use archive formats, use bz2 in HDFS

Thanks for your reply. Any reason why non splittable files must be ready sequentially even if they are present in multiple blocks?

Imagine I have JSON records within the gz file. There's a record that gets split between two blocks. The first block must be read, and store a partial JSON document in memory, then fetch the next block, before it can continue parsing that object.

Parsing can happen once entire data is fetched. My question is, I'll fetch block 1, keep it in memory, wait for blocks n-1 to be fetched completely (I'm assuming all blocks are being fetched in parallel here), once all blocks have been fetched I'll just stitch them together. I don't see any reason why should it fetch one after another? Let it parse and give results once all the blocks are fetched, no worries, but why spawn only 1 task to fetch data from multiple data nodes? This isn't making sense to me

I'm not sure the answer to that. I think it depends what node/rack the blocks are hosted on
